# What does this log message mean in android studio log during interaction of native code with USB device?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, native, android-permissions

I get this warning when I try to read a USB device

```
06-14 15:19:57.926 14580-14580/sadboy.circadian W/adboy.circadian: type=1400 audit(0.0:671): avc: denied { search } for name="usb" dev="tmpfs" ino=6196 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:usb_device:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

Comment: `I get this error ..` but the logline you posted is a warning

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII Okay, I have edited the details.

Comment: Which version of Android? Did you make sure you have permission to use USB first?

Comment: @zenzelezz I use marshmallow and I also get permission to use USB feature from the user too. I just wanted to know what causes this message. I found that this is related to SELinux permissive mode somehow but I am not sure.